# Recursive Trigger / Trigger Context Issue

Tags: apex, trigger, triggercontext

So there are tons of questions on here an d on the boards around using static variables to keep trigger from recursively calling itself.  There also is a lot of information out there around best practices in triggers.  These bets practices include only having one trigger per object and executing all logic outside of the trigger itself in a helper class.  My issue seems to be trying to merge these two best practices.  Helper classes for triggers, and use of static variables to prevent recursive trigger calls

Just for simplicity sake, lets assume the logic in the helper classes is ok.  It's bulkified, its optimized, etc.  Here is my Account Trigger

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, after insert, before update, after update) {

    AccountTriggerHelper helper = new AccountTriggerHelper();

    if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate){
        helper.updateAccountUpdateSummary(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);    
    }   

    if(trigger.isAfter){
        if(trigger.isUpdate){
            helper.maintainCAAccountTeamMembers(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isUpdate);
            helper.updateCortextOpportunityOwners(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);
        }
        if(trigger.isInsert){
            helper.maintainCAAccountTeamMembers(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isUpdate);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I just have a helper class that I call the methods to execute the logic for the trigger.  These all work great if I have them separated (each their own trigger). v The issue is I have test code that when I run is erroring out with a 'Too many SOQL queries' error.

When I check the debug logs, it seems that my triggers are being called recuresively, and it keeps going until it has run enough times in the same context to get the too many SOQL queries error.

So I thought I would use my TriggerContextUtility class to help with this.  Its just a class with a static variable to keep track of the first run of the trigger.  This works fine in my triggers with only one method being called.

Heres the triggerContetUtility class

```
public class TriggerContextUtility {

    private static boolean firstRun = true;

    public static boolean isFirstRun() {
        return firstRun;
    }
    public static void setFirstRunFalse(){
        firstRun = false;
    }
}
```

Very simple.  Normally, I would use this utility class like below to ensure that the trigger only fires once per context, but adding it like below doesn't work

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, after insert, before update, after update) {

    AccountTriggerHelper helper = new AccountTriggerHelper();
    if(TriggerContextUtility.isFirstRun()){
        if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate){
            helper.updateAccountUpdateSummary(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);    
        }   

        if(trigger.isAfter){
            if(trigger.isUpdate){
                helper.maintainCAAccountTeamMembers(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isUpdate);
                helper.updateCortextOpportunityOwners(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);
            }
            if(trigger.isInsert){
                helper.maintainCAAccountTeamMembers(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isUpdate);
            }
        }
    }
    TriggerContextUtility.setFirstRunFalse();
}
```

This does not work however.  It seems my before methods are called, but not my after methods.  I have tried moving the `TriggerContextUtility.setFirstRunFalse();` into different places, but nothing seems to correctly fire all methods.

So I either leave out my static variable check and the trigger is recursively calling itself until it errors out.  OR, I fix this recursive call using my TriggerContextUtility class, but then not all methods within the trigger are being called.

Can anyone offer any insight as to what I am doing wrong here?  Am I missing something.  This seems like something that should be simple, but for some reason I can't get it to work.  Hoping for another set of eyes to find the flaw in my logic here.

> EDIT

```
Here is the debug statements I added to the trigger

trigger AccountUpdatesTrigger on Account (before insert, after insert, before update, after update) {

    AccountTriggerHelper helper = new AccountTriggerHelper();
    if(TriggerContextUtility.isFirstRun()){
        if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate){
            helper.updateAccountUpdateSummary(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);    
        }   
        *system.debug('First Run Value Line 8: ' + TriggerContextUtility.isFirstRun());*

        if(trigger.isAfter){
            if(trigger.isUpdate){
                *system.debug('First Run Value Line 11: ' + TriggerContextUtility.isFirstRun());*
                helper.maintainCAAccountTeamMembers(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isUpdate);
                helper.updateCortextOpportunityOwners(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);
                *system.debug('First Run Value Line 14: ' + TriggerContextUtility.isFirstRun());*
            }
            if(trigger.isInsert){
                *system.debug('First Run Value Line 17: ' + TriggerContextUtility.isFirstRun());*

                helper.maintainCAAccountTeamMembers(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isUpdate);
            }
            TriggerContextUtility.setFirstRunFalse();
        }
    }   
}
```

The line 14 debug statement is outputting FALSE.  Why would that be?

Comment: What happens if you remove the isBefore block? Does the isAfter block get called as expected?

Comment: If I remove the before block the only method that runs is the method within that block.  None of the After methods are called

Comment: Why is the recursion happening? It seems like your problem is in your helper code, which we can't see. As a general rule of thumb, you shouldn't be performing a DML on the object you're on in your after trigger. This can create recursion. That logic should be in the before trigger.

Comment: I find setting static variables immediately before a DML is the only way to have precise control. With that then, I recommend moving the setting of your static variable to you helper class.

Comment: So would I set it inside each individual method within the helper class, as @britishBoyinDC suggested?

Comment: Methods that involve a DML, that you know is going to trip your trigger again, yes.

Comment: So if i have a helpoer method for each DML possibility say beforeupdatemethod, afterupdatemethod, etc. Would I need a seperate static variable for each?  or can I use my utilityclass in each helper method?

Comment: As long as you understand the order of operations, you can use the same static variable.

Comment: basically your saying i need 7 helper methods one for each DML possibility befiore insert, before update, etc.  As long as i order them according to the trigger order of execution, i should be all set

Comment: That is how I have always built my triggers/classes - I have always used these posts as my guide. http://gokubi.com/archives/two-interesting-ways-to-architect-apex-triggers
And...
http://www.embracingthecloud.com/2010/07/08/ASimpleTriggerTemplateForSalesforce.aspx
There are (many!) more variations, but I would keep simple at this stage...

Comment: Not the DML that originally fires your trigger but the DML that is happening in your helper class. There wouldn't be recursion if you weren't firing some action that caused the trigger to trip again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you want the ContentUtility check to be at the Trigger level - I typically refer to it in my helper class, or even at the individual method level in that class. There may well be instances where you want one method to run twice if something was updated, but not others. So I would move the check for TriggerContextUtility into the helper class and I think it will work fine...

As an update - I have always used these posts as my guide.

http://gokubi.com/archives/two-interesting-ways-to-architect-apex-triggers
http://www.embracingthecloud.com/2010/07/08/ASimpleTriggerTemplateForSalesforce.aspx

There are (many!) more variations, but I would keep simple at this stage... – BritishBoyinDC 1 min ago edit

Comment: hmmmm....sO i would add a check for first run in each method in the helper class and then set it to false at the end of each method.  Isnt each method call in the same context though?  So wont it be set to false after I call the first method, so then when I call the second method in the helper class, wont it still be false and therefore skip that method?

Comment: I would add the check at the method level where appropriate - but I would typically toggle the flag at the end of the logic for the after update process - it is the update process you want to avoid happening recursively...

Comment: To expand on that, I would change your structure to call methods in the helper class that correspond to the events in the trigger e.g. helper.beforeinsert, helper.afterupdate - and then within those, callout to the individual pieces of logic. That way, the final line of the helper.afterupdate method sets the firstrun to false.

Comment: Ok, so really, then I could have a construct to follow where each trigger has a helperclass with exactly 7 methods, one for each DML option.  Rather than having methods for function, like i Have now, where an afterupdate for example could possible call 3 methods?

Comment: This is how I've always controlled recursion, good answer.

Comment: I actually used the Mike Leach article you posted when building this construct, but it has no checks for recursion, which is what I was trying to do here

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following version?

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, after insert, before update, after update) {

    AccountTriggerHelper helper = new AccountTriggerHelper();
    if(TriggerContextUtility.isFirstRun()){
        if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate){
            helper.updateAccountUpdateSummary(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);    
        }   

        if(trigger.isAfter){
            if(trigger.isUpdate){
                helper.maintainCAAccountTeamMembers(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isUpdate);
                helper.updateCortextOpportunityOwners(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);
            }
            if(trigger.isInsert){
                helper.maintainCAAccountTeamMembers(trigger.new, trigger.old, trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isUpdate);
            }

            TriggerContextUtility.setFirstRunFalse();
         }

     }

}
```

I would expect this to work because:

1. Your before update trigger fires, static variable is true so the
   first if is true and the before update is executed.
2. Context variable is still true
3. After trigger fires, still the first if (TriggerContextUtility.setFirstRunFalse()) is true so trigger.isAfter part is executed and at the end the static variable is set to false.
4. I guess you have workflows updating thus the trigger is invoked once again but this time the first if should be false... the end

I also prefer to have the trigger stoppers in the trigger because it makes it more readable... It's also part of the trigger logic and not the Helper Class logic right ?

Comment: I have tried that.  If I do that none of the after trigger methods get called.

Comment: really ? :( can you add debug statements at the top to report the static variable value ?

Comment: HMMMM.....I added debug statements and found something.  I updated the question with the debug results.  What do you think?

Comment: can it be that any of the two methods in between also sets the static variable ? or maybe they are re triggering Account triggers

Comment: No, neither of them make any mention of the static variable

Comment: then what about re triggering the Account triggers ?